# Postgresql Recursive Return Qualifier

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, tree

I'm working with hierarchies in Postgresql for the first time.  Is it possible to qualify a node given the state of its children?

Take this example case:

```
create table Org (
  id int primary key UNIQUE,
  name varchar(64),
  parent_id int,
  late boolean
)

create table Person (
  id int primary key UNIQUE,
  name varchar(64),
  org_id int, constraint person_org_fk foreign key (org_id) references Org(id)
)

INSERT INTO Org (id, name, parent_id, late) VALUES
 (1, 'Top', null, false),
 (2, 'Second', 1, false),
 (3, 'Left', 2, false),
 (4, 'Right', 2, false),
 (5, 'Blue', 3, false),
 (6, 'Red', 4, true);

INSERT INTO Person (id, name, org_id) VALUES
 (1, 'Bob', 1),
 (2, 'Karen', 1),
 (3, 'Jim', 2),
 (4, 'Tess', 4),
 (5, 'Will', 3);
```

I can walk the tree with this recursive query:

```
with recursive org_hierarchy as (
  select org.id, org.name, org.name::TEXT as "path", person.name as "persons" from org
  join person on person.org_id = org.id
  where org.id = 1
  UNION all
  select org.id, org.name, org_hierarchy."path" || ' => ' || org.name as "path", person.name from org
  join org_hierarchy on org_hierarchy.id = org.parent_id
  join person on person.org_id = org.id
)
select id, name, "path", array_agg(distinct "persons") from org_hierarchy
group by id, name, "path"
order by id
```

---

```
 id |  name  |          path          |  managers
----+--------+------------------------+-------------
  1 | Top    | Top                    | {Bob,Karen}
  2 | Second | Top => Second          | {Jim}
  3 | Left   | Top => Second => Left  | {Will}
  4 | Right  | Top => Second => Right | {Tess}
(4 rows)
```

There is a single org that is marked as late.  The way the query works it builds a result set as it descends into the tree.  I would like to write a query that lists all managers who oversee groups that are late.  In this case Jim would be excluded.  I'm not sure how to accomplish that.